# Create an index and use it as a hint in a select statement in the same batch in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

I want to compare the performance of the query between the cases when a certain index is present vs when the index is not present using execution plan window of SSMS.

I am using AdventureWorks2012 database. 
Following is my sample query.

```
SELECT TOP 10000 SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID, CarrierTrackingNumber
, OrderQty, ProductID, SpecialOfferID, UnitPrice, UnitPriceDiscount, LineTotal, rowguid, ModifiedDate
  FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
  where SalesOrderID = 57058; 


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SalesOrderDetail_SALESDETAIL ON Sales.SalesOrderDetail
  (SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID, CarrierTrackingNumber
, OrderQty, ProductID, SpecialOfferID, UnitPrice, UnitPriceDiscount, LineTotal, rowguid, ModifiedDate)


SELECT TOP 10000 SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID, CarrierTrackingNumber
, OrderQty, ProductID, SpecialOfferID, UnitPrice, UnitPriceDiscount, LineTotal, rowguid, ModifiedDate
  FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail WITH(INDEX(IX_SalesOrderDetail_SALESDETAIL))
  where SalesOrderID = 57058;
```

It gives me the following error message:

Index 'IX_SalesOrderDetail_SALESDETAIL' on table 'Sales.SalesOrderDetail' (specified in the FROM clause) does not exist.

I was expecting the index which is created in the previous line will be available for the next line.

Can any body guide me what's going wrong or what i am missing or how to achieve what i am looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilation happens per batch, not per line. Before the first `SELECT` happens or the index is created, a plan needs to be devised for the second `SELECT`, which fails since the index does not yet exist.

Put a `GO` after the `CREATE INDEX` to start a new batch.

Comment: And take the hint out. Seriously. It likeiy is 99.999% not needed - sql server is not stupid when selecting indices.

Comment: @jeroen, i think you are not completely correct. Even if i removed the first select statement and use only the second select statement then also the same issue occurs.

Can you add more details or give sample if you meant something else?

Comment: The statement will be compiled twice. Once when the batch is compiled then the addition of the index will cause a recompile when it is executed. So it should pick up the existence of the index automatically without the hint then.

Comment: @Satyajit: Forget the first `SELECT`, it's irrelevant to the issue. You need a `GO` after `CREATE INDEX` before you can use it in subsequent statements.

Comment: @TomTom, as mentioned in the first line 'I want to compare the performance of the query'.

I am using it only for testing or learning process. It's not for use in real time.

Thanks :)

Comment: @MartinSmith: the batch as presented here will not compile at all because the second `SELECT` cannot be compiled, so the index will not be created either. The `CREATE INDEX` really needs to happen separately. You are correct, however, that once the index is created, the hint should be superfluous because SQL Server will figure out how to use the index itself (as @TomTom pointed out).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Thanks for your answer. it works as expected now :)